# TypeError: regForm is null

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript and I'm still figuring out how it all works + I haven't done any other programming language before so I'm pretty lost and now I'm working on a JavaScript lab for my web unit and we're working on validating a form (the form's id is "regForm") through JavaScript.

This is my JavaScript so far:

```
function validate() {
    var errMsg = ""; // stores error message
    var result = true; // no errors
}

function init(){
    var regForm = document.getElementById("regForm"); 
    regForm.onsubmit = validate;
} 

window.onload = init;
```

This is an exact replica of my teacher's notes, so I'd expect it to work. But in the firefox firebug validator I still get this error message:

```
"TypeError: regForm is null"
```

Which seems odd, because it works if I open his files and tests that one. Does anybody know what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: you'll need to show your markup/HTML .

Answer (score 0):

We are missing your HTML. Please can you post this?

From first glance, it looks like you are missing a `<element id="regForm">`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a form with `id="regForm"`

Check below snippet.

```js
function validate() {
    var errMsg = ""; // stores error message
    var result = true; // no errors
    alert("Validating");
}

function init(){
alert("Init fn.");
    var regForm = document.getElementById("regForm"); 
    regForm.onsubmit = validate;
} 

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<form id="regForm">
<input type="text" name="a"/>
<input type="submit" name="btn"/>
</form>
```